# AngularJS adding object to array updates all similar objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting data from a WebAPI and storing it in a scoped variable array products.

```
$scope.products
```

I also have a second scoped array

```
$scope.selectedFish = [];
```

What I am trying to do is find a product in the products array, modify it and add it into the selectedProducts array.

I have the following function declared on the same controller.

```
// Function to add a new fish to the selectedFish array
            $scope.add = function() {
                // Find existing fish from products list
                var newFishToAdd = $filter('filter') ($scope.products, { Id: $scope.selectedProduct });
                // Change the name property
                newFishToAdd[0].FishName = $scope.selectProductName;
                // Add new fish to the selected fish array
                $scope.selectedFish.push(newFishToAdd[0]);
                $scope.bindModel();
            }
```

This does work, but I am having difficulty where if I add the same product twice with different FishName values, it updates all entries in the array for the same selectedProduct with the last FishName entered.

Comment: You are pushing the same element i guess.. `$scope.selectedFish.push(newFishToAdd[0]);` use angular.copy for deep copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happening as object reference is same. use angular.copy().

```
$scope.add = function() {
    // Find existing fish from products list
    var newFishToAdd = $filter('filter')($scope.products, { Id: $scope.selectedProduct });

    var obj = angular.copy(newFishToAdd[0]);
    obj.FishName = $scope.selectProductName;

    // Add new fish to the selected fish array
    $scope.selectedFish.push(obj);
    $scope.bindModel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using angular.copy for this purpose. As it says in angular documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

`angular.copy`

Creates a deep copy of source, which should be an object or an array.

If no destination is supplied, a copy of the object or array is created.

If a destination is provided, all of its elements (for arrays) or properties (for objects) are deleted and then all elements/properties from the source are copied to it.

If `source` is not an `object`or `array`(inc. `null`and `undefned`), `source` is returned.
If `source` is identical to `destination` an `exception` will be thrown.